# Is it possible to cast a delayed resurrection spell on myself?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, resurrection

Knowing the location of the corpse of oneself in spacetime, is it somehow possible to set up (e.g. in combination w/ other spells) and cast on it a successful delayed resurrection? Or maybe even a delayed true auto-resurrect without the corpse?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to delay the Revivify spell so it's activated when a character dies?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/126117/is-it-possible-to-delay-the-revivify-spell-so-its-activated-when-a-character-di)

Comment: Not a duplicate but also relevant information: [Can the trigger for Contingency be your own death?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/100709/can-the-trigger-for-contingency-be-your-own-death)

Comment: Impressed that this isn't linked yet: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/123671/43856

Answer (score 5):

### Contingency

*Contingency* allows you to delay the effect of a spell

> Instead, it takes effect when a trigger that you describe occurs.

Use *contingency* with either *revivify* or *raise dead* as the contingent spell, and describe the trigger as you wish.

Note that the spell only has a duration of **10 days,** and ends if you are ever separated from the statue of yourself (the material component).

You can't also use *resurrection* (level 7) or *true resurrection* (level 9), because *contingency* only allows level 5 or less spell to be used as the contingent.

This combination is available earliest on **level 16**: when you spend 11 levels to wizard to gain *contingency* and 5 levels to cleric or paladin to gain *revivify* OR 7 levels to cleric or bard or paladin to gain *raise dead*.

Comment: You should probably mention that you can only cast both contingency and resurrection spells via either magical secrets or intensive multiclassing.

Comment: @miniman Oh, good point, I hadn't thought of the multiclassing requirement on this combo. I guess setting up a simple cure spell to go off *before* you die (like say 'when I drop to 0 hit points') would be significantly cheaper to pull off, both in terms of spellcaster levels and material components.

Comment: I was hoping for a way w/ resurrect but this is also interesting (I actually read about the revivify+contingency setup here before I posted my question, so it's not a duplicate). Do I understand correctly that the material component of revivify is a statue of the revivifiee? And one can be dead max 10 days for revivify to work? And what about raise dead?

Comment: You can achieve this as a 14th level bard, due to magic secrets

Answer (score 1):

### Glyph of Warding (PHB 245-246)

This 3rd-level wizard spell lets you put down, in essence, a magical mine to go off. You can use its **Spell Glyph** option to store with it any reviving spell you can cast (*revivify*, *raise dead*, *resurrection*, though those require multiclassing) with the trigger set to 'when a creature touching this glyph dies' or some such.

It costs 200gp along with 1 hour of casting time for the glyph, plus at least 300gp for *revivify* (more for bigger spells), can be done as early as level 10 (5 in wizard, 5 in cleric or druid), and needs to be placed exactly where the creature will die (but you state this foreknowledge is a given). Unlike *contingency*, it isn't limited to working on just you.

### Clone (PHB p. 222)

This 8th-level wizard spell lets you grow a new body for the target to 'respawn' in when they die. It costs a cubic inch of the target's flesh, along with 2000gp for the reusable tank, 1000gp per grown corpse, and a development period of 120 days, and also isn't limited to just reviving yourself. It also doesn't require multiclassing (though it does require a 15th-level wizard to cast) and doesn't care where the target is when they die.

Comment: Please remember to be nice to each other if you feel the need to argue about whether an approach suggested in an answer actually works.